# Configure Hive Metastore for presto and query data from s3 and apache kudu

Tags: hive, presto, apache-kudu, hive-metastore

I am pretty new to Presto and hive. In one of our application we want to use presto to query data from apache kudu and aws s3. As per my knowledge presto has its own catalog(meta) service, but we want to configure hive metastore(without hadoop and hive) so that in future other application(e.g spark) can use hive metastore to query data from Kudu and s3. I have been using latest version of presto and kudu.

Could someone help me to configure this system?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Presto is a federated SQL engine, and delegates metadata completely to the target system... so there is not a builtin "catalog(meta) service".  In the case of the Hive connector, Presto use the standard the Hive metastore client, and directly connect to HDFS, S3, GCS, etc, to read data.

BTW if you are on AWS, I’d recommend using the AWS Glue metastore, instead of the Hive metastore, since it is a managed service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html

Comment: This question was also asked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/j455zkrWMpY

Comment: @DainSundstrom you said `Presto use the standard the Hive metastore client, and directly connect to HDFS, S3, GCS, etc, to read data`. Does this mean that we need to install `hive metastore client` first and then have settings added into `/etc/catalog/hive.properties` ?

Comment: No you don't need to install anything.  Everything is shipped with the server.